# React Graphql Typescript file set up

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I'm just starting to look at creating a React Graphql and Typescript app

I have the schema and resolvers and a server working using apollo-server, I can see the graphql playground.

I also have a client folder that contains my react app. I created the react app using the --typescript flag so it produces .tsx files and a tsconfig.json.

I'm looking into creating a Typescript definitions for the graphql queries

So my file structure is something like this.

```
client
    react.tsx files

package.json
resolvers.js
schema.js
server.js
```

My simple question is should the server side files like schema.js and resolvers.js be .js files or should they somehow be .ts files. I'm sure they should be .js files but I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider looking into a tool like [apollo-codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#code-generation) for this. Otherwise you'll have to write out your typescript types manually.

For a small project, this may be trivial, but for a larger one you might want to start generating the types based on the gql schema as your source of truth.

Comment: I am using apollo to do this